# webpack reload styles without page refresh

Tags: javascript, webpack, livereload

I use webpack and livereload plugin but when I change something in styles, page refresh but I don't want it.

When I use gulp, I change anything in styles and save it and then css reload without page refresh.

Why does not work like gulp on webpack?

Codes are below

> webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const WebpackNotifierPlugin = require("webpack-notifier");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const LiveReloadPlugin = require("webpack-livereload-plugin");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        "./resources/js/app.jsx",
        "./resources/scss/app.scss",
    ],
    devtool: "source-map",
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public/assets"),
        filename: "js/app.js",
        publicPath: "/public/assets/"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    presets: ["env", "react", 'stage-2']
                }
            }
        }, {
            test: /\.(scss)$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['css-loader', 'sass-loader', "postcss-loader"])
        }]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"]
    },
    watch: true,
    plugins: [
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
            from: "node_modules/bootstrap/dist",
            to: "plugins/bootstrap"
        }, , {
            from: 'node_modules/font-awesome/css',
            to: 'plugins/font-awesome/css',
        }, {
            from: 'node_modules/font-awesome/fonts',
            to: 'plugins/font-awesome/fonts',
        }]),
        new WebpackNotifierPlugin({
            alwaysNotify: true
        }),
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            debug: true
        }),
        new LiveReloadPlugin(),
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: 'css/app.css'
        }),
        new Dotenv({
            path: './.env',
            safe: true
        }),
        new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin(['NODE_ENV'])
    ],
    node: {
        fs: "empty"
    }
};
```

> package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback --progress --colors",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --progress --color",
    "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --progress --color"
  },
```

I use "npm run dev" command.
Where is the problem ?

Comment: You might wanna take a look at https://github.com/lshih/webpack-extract-css-hot-reload

You can use the regular extract text in prod mode and the hot reloading one in dev mode.

Comment: i don't use dev server . i think problem is here. dev server and dev server hot reload used in all given example. am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

**ExtractTextPlugin** sadly doesn't support hot module replacement.

From the page plugin description:

> No Hot Module Replacement

what you need to do is use the plugin just in production.

```
rules: [
  ...
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ?
      ExtractTextPlugin.extract([
        "css-loader", "sass-loader", "postcss-loader"
      ]) : [
        { loader: "style-loader" },
        { loader: "css-loader" },
        { loader: "sass-loader" },
        { loader: "postcss-loader" }
      ]
  }
]
```

Comment: my first guess is that you are missing some configuration, I was in the same point you are some months ago. You can look at [here](https://github.com/arkgast/react-firebase-starter/tree/603b8fb21a65f94ca5d63c338a294975b7aa4517) to see how it's working (review carefully the config folder).

Comment: i checked out it but it is very complicated for me this time cos i am newbie on this so sorry

Comment: Don't worry it's my fault. [Here](https://github.com/arkgast/react-webpack-boilerplate) I have a simplier example. Maybe you are newbie now but in some time you'll be good enough to help people. As I told you some time ago I was in the same point you are, just keep going.

Comment: thank you so much for encourage. i am working hardly and i will learn it soon and help the others like you. :)

Answer (score -2):

Try like this it will work.

```
{
   test: /\.(s*)css$/,
   loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(['style-loader', 'css-loader', "sass-loader"])
}
```

If you share the package.json than it will be helpful for others to solve the issue.

Comment: i will try . share the package.json all of ?

Comment: Ok.I assume you installed the dependencies which i mentioned.I will try and let you know.